# Properties of a red-black tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

```
      35 (black)
    /    \
  21      54 (whole row is red)
 /  \    /  \
14  27  42  74 (whole row is black)
              \
              90 (red)
```

Would this classify as a **red-black tree**, I have not spotted any violations. What are primarily the properties I should look out for besides you can't have two consecutive red nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no violations in the above tree.

The main properties to look out for are :

1) Root is Black

2) There cannot be 2 consecutive red nodes.

3) You need to add NIL Nodes as leaf nodes, whose color is taken as black.

4) The `Black Depth` of all nodes from the root is always the same, eg in the above case the `Black Depth is 3` including the NIL Nodes on each path.

You can read about them here : [Red Black Tree Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties)